# How to get ClusterManager click and ClusterManager item click in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am developing Map Based application, I used cluster for arranging markers. It works fine. Now, I need to show a message when I click on clusterManager, and when I click on item (Only one marker), So that I can make the diffrence between them.

Here it is my code, `setOnClusterClickListener` and `setOnClusterItemClickListener` doesn't called, So please What's going wrong in my code.

```
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, getMap());

    getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
    try {
        readItems();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Problem reading list of markers.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyItem>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
            Log.d("cluster","clicked");
            return true;
        }
    });
    mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClusterItemClick(MyItem item) {
            Log.d("cluster item","clicked");
            return true;
        }
    });
    getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
```

Answer (score 5):

you should call setOnMarkerClickListener before setOnClusterClickListener and setOnClusterItemClickListener

```
mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, getMap());
getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager); // 
getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
try {
    readItems();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Problem reading list of markers.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
        Log.d("cluster","clicked");
        return true;
    }
});
mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(MyItem item) {
        Log.d("cluster item","clicked");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Where do you call `clusterManager.cluster()`?